# How to create serializer with nested data DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have seen many tutorials about nested serializer, but unfortunately I can`t solve this task. Please, give me some tips.

I need to create this JSON

```
{
        "external_id": "11",
        "details": [
            {
                "amount": 7,
                "price": "12.00",
                "product": {
                    "name": "Car"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

My models consist the next relative:

```
from django.db import models


class Order(models.Model):
    NEW = 'new'
    ACCEPTED = 'accepted'
    FAILED = 'failed'

    order_status = [
        (NEW, 'new'),
        (ACCEPTED, 'accepted'),
        (FAILED, 'failed'),
    ]

    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=order_status, default='new', blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    external_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Order № {self.external_id}'


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name='details',
                              null=True, blank=True)

    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='product',
                                null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Detail for {self.order}, detail for product {self.product}'
```

My view

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    pagination_class = ContentRangeHeaderPagination

class OrderDetailViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = OrderDetail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderDetailSerializer
```

My serializer

```
class OrderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderDetail
        fields = ['id', 'amount', 'price']
        depth = 1


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = OrderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'product']

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = OrderDetailSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id', 'status', 'created_at', 'external_id', 'details']
        depth = 2

    def create(self, validated_data):  # works for first nesting
        print(validated_data)
        details_data = validated_data.pop('details')  
        request = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for detail_data in details_data:  # 
            products_data = detail_data.pop('product')
            request_detail = OrderDetail.objects.create(order=request, **detail_data)

            for product_data in products_data:
                Product.objects.create(product=request_detail, **product_data)

        return request
```

I have errors when I try to send POST request. => KeyError 'products'
I wanted to get **product** fields using a loop. But I can't get this field, because I didn't identified it.
My question is: **how to receive this field in OrderSerializer**.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to use this serializer for read-only operations or do you want to use it to create new orders?

Comment: Add `product`field in `OrderDetailSerializer`?

Comment: Yes, I want to use it for create new orders!

Comment: When I add product in OrderDetailSerializer it doesn`t work